# How can I generate a dynamic series in Power BI, for which the first value depends on a measure, and then plot on a visual?

Tags: dynamic, powerbi, measure, timeserieschart, generate

Looking to generate a series of dates and values on Power BI for which the first value and the increments depend on measures. (Dynamic series generation and then applying to visuals).

Tried do to this through a calculated column, however this was unsuccessful as the column is calculated before the filtering on the measure can occur - so it was providing me with undesired results.

I have also tried to use GENERATESERIES within a measure with UNION to combine the date and values series. However, I am then unable to plot this on a visual as I have multiple values for my measure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers

GDB007

Comment: Perhaps your trying to apply suboptimal solution to your problem. What is it that you're trying to achieve business wise? Can you display your desired end result and base data?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have a fixed X-axis, you can certainly define the Y-values dynamically using measures that are dynamic.

For example:

[image: Chart]

In this example, I just defined the `[StartValue]` measure as a constant 1 but it could be whatever you like. The `[Increment]` measure here just reads in the value of a small parameter table I created to show multiple values simultaneously by dropping that column in the Legend field of the visual, but this could also be whatever you like.